# Android: Shared Preferences & Setters and Getters

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, getter-setter

I'm using a simple set & get class so that I can retrieve a variable throughout my app but I need to store this class for later use so I want to use shared preferences to store it but I am not sure how to implement this correctly. I tried to implementing the shared preferences within the setter method and there are no errors but this crashes when I run.

Here is the class

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.widget.EditText;



public class Passcode extends Activity {

    private String pin;
    public static final String PREFS_PASS = "MyPrefsFile";
    EditText txtNewPin = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_EnterNewPin);
    SharedPreferences Pincode = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_PASS,0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = Pincode.edit();

    public String getPin() {
        Pincode.getString(pin,"0000");
        return pin;
    }

    public void setPin(String pin) {

        editor.putString(pin, txtNewPin.getText().toString());
        editor.commit();

    }


}
```

Comment: So many missing things in this code snippet that i suggest that you should read more on android and activities. To sart with you should override `onCreate()` load your layout there and after yiuve done that you can set your `EditText` using `findViewById()`, see answers for the shared preferences handling.

Comment: Im not sure i explained this correctly but this is not meant to be a activity i only made it to be able to bring in the EditText from another xml file i simply want to be able to go object.setPin in other classes ans have the value stored in shared preferences and be able to call it by going object.getPin

Comment: Okey, but you must anyway load your layout before you can access UI widgets within the layout. But you have your layout loaded in some class, right? Why don't you have your getters and setters in there?

Comment: Did the answers help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below method for get and set variable in shared preference.

```
 /**
 * This method is used to set shared preferences
 * @param context Application context
 * @param key shared object key
 * @param value shared object value
 */
public static void setPreferences(Context context, String key, String value) {
    SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    Editor prefsEditor = appSharedPrefs.edit();
    prefsEditor.putString(key, value);
    prefsEditor.commit();
}

/**
 * This method is used to get shared object
 * @param context Application context
 * @param key shared object key
 * @return return value, for default "" asign.
 */
public static String getPreferences(Context context, String key) {

    SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

    String json = appSharedPrefs.getString(key, "");
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(json)) {
        return null;
    }
    return json;
}
```

It is worked for me.

Comment: Thanks this is more or less what i ended up doing and so far it works just fine

Answer (score 0):

where is the oncreate method ? 
suppose u want to manipulate  a boolean value in shared pref :

```
      SharedPreferences  SharedPref_;
       Editor _prefsEditor;
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     // to get
    SharedPref_ = this.getSharedPreferences("MainPref", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            downloaded = SharedPref_.getBoolean("Downloaded", false) ;

    // to set a shared pref : 
    _prefsEditor = SharedPref_.edit(); 
            downloaded =  true;
            _prefsEditor.putBoolean("Downloaded",true);
            _prefsEditor.commit();


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can initialize your EditText outside of a method because the layout may not be set. For that reason, I'll put it inside the methods. The same applies to the SharedPreferences. Just put it all in the methods:

```
private String pin;
public static final String PREFS_PASS = "MyPrefsFile";

public String getPin() {
    EditText txtNewPin = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_EnterNewPin);
    SharedPreferences Pincode = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_PASS,0);
    Pincode.getString(pin,"0000");
    return pin;
}

public void setPin(String pin) {
    SharedPreferences Pincode = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_PASS,0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = Pincode.edit();
    editor.putString(pin, txtNewPin.getText().toString());
    editor.commit();
}
```

However I also see one more problem: `String pin` is never initialized. Make sure that is has a value before you use it in `Pincode.getString(pin, "0000");`